# Formats to use on a response with fast-json-stringify

Tags: stringify, fastify

What I want to do is add validation to the schema response from a fastify route.

Following the documentation from Fastify [here](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Validation-and-Serialization/#core-concepts) we can see this

> Ajv for the validation of a request
> fast-json-stringify for the serialization of a response's body

Related to improve and add validations for a response, what I want to do is check the schema when I send a response.

[fast-json-stringify](https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify#fastjsonstringifyschema) support different options, included format, but if you read the documentation, they said that they support JSON schema. Jsonschema has support for email format, that you can see [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#built-in-formats) as a built-in format but when I try to use it on Fastify, like this:

```
{
  response: {
    200: {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['email'],
      properties: {
        email: {
          type: 'string',
          format: 'email',
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And try to return ad response this

```
reply.code(200).send({ email: 'test' })
```

The only validation that I can do is when I set the type to integer and try to return a string.

Did you know if it's possible to use ajv-formats with fast-json-stringify to add validation to the response schema and use the formats from ajv and add new ones?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fast-json-stringify` does the serialization, not the validation.

The json schema provided to it will be used to serialize only the `properties` declared and some type checking like `integer` or `array`s.

- the `enum` keyword is not supported
- the `format` keyword is supported only for the dates [as documented](https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify#fastjsonstringifyschema):

[image]

To reach your goal, you should use this plugin: [`fastify-response-validation`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-response-validation#fastify-response-validation) that will add a validation step of your response body **before** the serialization process.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know this plugin :D